# How to find the value of $m$ given $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

given $(X,Y)$ random variable 2D continuously with the density function $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{{30}}\cdot x^{m}\cdot ye^{-y} & x \in [0,y] \ , \ y>0 \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I need to find the value of $m$

I know I should use the properties of the density function $$1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy$$ $$1=\int_{0}^{y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{30}}\cdot x^{m}\cdot ye^{-y}dxdy$$

I dont understand how to determine the limits of $x$ from the given about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the computation of $\displaystyle\iint_{\Bbb R^2}f(x,y)\; dx\; dy$ you can use Fubini and

- either let $y$ run in the interval $[0,\infty)$, and *then* $x\in[0,y]$,
- or let $x$ run in the interval $[0,\infty)$, and *then* $y\in[x,\infty)$.

The two ways are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &=
\int_{y\in[0,\infty)}dy\int_{x\in[0,y]}
\frac 1{30}x^m\; y\; e^{-y}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_{y\in[0,\infty)}dy\cdot
\frac 1{30}\cdot\frac {y^{m+1}}{m+1}y\; e^{-y}\\
&=
\frac 1{30(m+1)}\cdot \Gamma(m+3)
\qquad\text{ and if $m$ is integer}
\\
&=
\frac 1{30(m+1)}\cdot (m+2)!
\\
&=\frac 1{30}(m+2)\cdot m!
\ ,
\\[4mm]
1 
&=
\int_{x\in[0,\infty)}dx\int_{y\in[x,\infty)}
\frac 1{30}x^m\; y\; e^{-y}\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x\in[0,\infty)}dx\cdot
\frac 1{30}x^m\; (x+1)\; e^{-x}
\\
&=\frac 1{30}\cdot(\Gamma(m+2)+\Gamma(m+1))
\qquad\text{ and if $m$ is integer}
\\
&=
\frac 1{30}\cdot ((m+1)!+m!)
\\
&=\frac 1{30}\cdot m!\cdot((m+1)+1)
\\
&=\frac 1{30}(m+2)\cdot m!
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For $m=3$ we have indeed equality.

---

The equation to be solved $(m+2)\Gamma(m+1)=30$ has a unique solution $m>0$ since the L.H.S. is an increasing function of $m$.

But note that the $\Gamma$ function comes with "its own caprice", we find for instance...

```
? plot(m=-.99, -0.9, (m+2)*gamma(m+1) - 30) 

70.426911 "''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
          :                                                              |
          |:                                                             |
          |"                                                             |
          |                                                              |
          | x                                                            |
          |                                                              |
          |  x                                                           |
          |   _                                                          |
          |                                                              |
          |    "                                                         |
          |     "                                                        |
          |      "                                                       |
          |       "_                                                     |
          |         "_                                                   |
          |           x_                                                 |
          |             "x_                                              |
          -----------------"x_--------------------------------------------
          |                   ""xx__                                     |
          |                         ""xx___                              |
          |                                """"xxxx____                  |
-19.53514 |............................................""""""xxxxxxxx_____
          -0.99                                                       -0.9
? solve(m=-.99, -0.9, (m+2)*gamma(m+1) - 30) 
%21 = -0.96617414943112079757353172624510260510
```